# i want to pass list as parameters in page navigation in windows7 using silverlight and access them in target page

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm new to Windows Phone 7 development.

In my First Application I want to Create two listboxes with checkboxes inside them in different pages and to fill the first listbox with some Data. When I select some records in first listbox, that particular records have to be added in another listbox. I done listbox selection and also pass the selecteditem via parameter to another page, when I tried to assign that list to `listbox.ItemSource` it throws `ArgumentNullException`.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, as you are pointing out, ArgumentNullException is being thrown. So basically when you are doing the assignment to ItemsSource you are providing a null. In other terms, the object you think you have received from the object page is null.

Secondly, it is hard to help you debug the problem if you are not providing any source code. But, generally speaking are you able to test with dummy data and from code-behind (i.e. not from the XAML) when you are in the 2nd page that the listbox there gets populated? So, for the time being ignore the passing of data. Just ensure that when the 2nd page is loaded, the listbox is populated with dummy data that you have created in the code-behind of that page. If that works then your problem is simpler.

Hopefully, this helps.

//-- Adding sample Code -- //

*Firstpage.xaml*

```
<ListBox x:Name="FirstListBox" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="HandleSelection">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="32" Margin="12"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

*Firstpage.xaml.cs*

```
FirstListBox.DataContext = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J" };
```

**...**

```
private void HandleSelection(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    String selection = (String)FirstListBox.SelectedItem;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Secondpage.xaml?id=" + selection, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

*Secondpage.xaml*

```
<ListBox x:Name="OtherListBox" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="32" Margin="12"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

*Secondpage.xaml.cs*

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    String id = null;
    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("id", out id);
    if (id != null)
    {
        List<String> dummyData = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            dummyData.Add(id + " - " + i);
        }
        OtherListBox.DataContext = dummyData;
    }
}
```

So, as you can read from the i have a dummy list in Firstpage and when i click on any of the items it takes me to another page where there is another list which have been populated with data generated from my initial selection. As you see i am passing the selection as a querystring parameter just like i explained in my comments of this answer.

Hopefully this solves your problem and i look forward to you accepting this solution as an answer to your problem.

Comment: ya in the second page when i used to fill some dummy data it gets filled on navigation,but when i tried to pass data as parameter it doesn't gets filled

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                id = i + 1;
                name = "productname" + i;
                quantity = i + 2 / 2;
                productlist.Add(new ProductList(id, name, quantity));
            }
            lstpro.ItemsSource = productlist;

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            res _res = new res(lstpro.SelectedItems);   
         
              NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/res.xaml" , UriKind.Relative));

        }

Comment: Could you edit your initial question and paste the code how you are passing the data to the next page and the code that receives it. From you above copy-paste you provided it seems that you are not having a querystring but rather a uri to the page to navigate to. In other terms, you should be doing something like that: 

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/res.xaml?id=1&name=A", UriKind.Relative).

But, what you could probably want to do is not pass data via the querystring but, perhaps saved the data in isolatedstorage when you select something on page 1 and retrieve that data on page 2.

Comment: I'm not use isolated storage,i just used to send the selecteditems as parameter in the code res _res=new res(lstpro.selecteditems) where i can able to access the list.i Think so that the Grid Doesn't load correctly when i pass the parameter in constructor.so what the listbox throws null exception

Comment: Sorry i cannot help you more as i do not see what you are really doing. For example, now i am confused by the fact that you seem to say that you are passing the selected item. So, are you passing the object? That won't work. Perhaps pass an index of the selected item and then use that on your other page to access the globally accessible data-structure in order to populate the 2nd listbox.

Comment: I modified my answer above to show you my point and which is a solution to your problem as far as i understand it.

Comment: thanks for your response,i already find the solution and i explain it that i was not passing only the selected value in **selectionchanged** event.i tried to pass the selected values as a list on button click event and I'm used   'PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["yourparam"] = lstpro.SelectedItems;' to store the value and retrieve it in second page

Comment: Here is My Code For Your reference.. where i'm adding the data to list and assign it to lisbox.itemsource                                                    ` for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                id = i + 1;
                name = "productname" + i;
                quantity = i + 2 / 2;
                productlist.Add(new ProductList(id, name, quantity));
            }
            lstpro.ItemsSource = productlist;`

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage


    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //adding data to listbox on page load event//
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            id = i + 1;
            name = "productname" + i;
            quantity = i + 2 / 2;
            productlist.Add(new ProductList(id, name, quantity));
        }
        lstpro.ItemsSource = productlist;

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          //using   PhoneApplicationService.Current.State to store the list//
          PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["yourparam"] = lstpro.SelectedItems;

          NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/res.xaml", UriKind.Relative))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

And in The Second Page...

<`private IList iList1;

```
  //In The onNavigatedTo Event assign the stored list to the variable//      
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {


         var i= PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["yourparam"];
         iList1 = (IList) i ;//convert object to list//
         lstpro.ItemsSource = iList1;

    }'
```